# How can I get more than one Doc in a Collection of a List of Strings? (Flutter)

Tags: list, firebase, flutter, dictionary, doc

My question is if I can put a List in a Doc from Firebase.
Here is my Code:

```
Future getPosts() async {
  var test = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Profiles")
      .doc(auth.currentUser.displayName)
      .collection("Following")
      .doc()
      .get()
      .asStream()
      .toList();
  print(test);

  qn = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Posts")
      .doc() // here I want the string of All documents from the List
      .collection("_Posts")
      .get();
}
```

The Code is pretty shitty but yeah hope you can Help.

Comment: The question isn't clear, you want to get a list of docs from a collection? because we use get() to fetch only one document.

Comment: Yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code implementing both `FutureBuilder()` and `StreamBuilder()`:

```
class PlayGround extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlayGround({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PlayGroundState createState() => _PlayGroundState();
}

class _PlayGroundState extends State<PlayGround> {
  FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          //using a Future ( Fetch once )
          Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<List<PostsModel>>(
            future: fetchUserPosts('someUID'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return LinearProgressIndicator();
              }
              return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                    child: Text(snapshot.data![index].title.toString()));
              });
            },
          )),

          //using a stream (Real Time)
          Expanded(
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: _db
                .collection('Users')
                .doc('someUID')
                .collection('Posts')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return LinearProgressIndicator();
              }
              List<PostsModel> _postsStream = snapshot.data!.docs
                  .map((e) =>
                      PostsModel.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
                  .toList();
              return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                    child: Text(_postsStream[index].title.toString()));
              });
            },
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
 //to get list of posts from Firestore
  Future<List<PostsModel>> fetchUserPosts(userID) async {
    var result = await _db
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(userID)
        .collection('Posts')
        // .orderBy("SomeThing")
        .get();

    List<PostsModel> postsModel =
        result.docs.map((doc) => PostsModel.fromMap(doc.data())).toList();

    return postsModel;
  }
}

class PostsModel {
  final String? title;
  final num? likes;

  PostsModel({
    this.title,
    this.likes,
  });

  factory PostsModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostsModel(
        title: json["title"],
        likes: json["likes"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "title": title,
        "likes": likes,
      };
}
```